# How to center multi column multi row environment in matrix

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

Using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351627/make-a-symbol-take-up-an-entire-multi-column-multi-row-sub-matrix) I was able to create a big zero but how can I center it? I'm a bit lost on the horizontal space.
How can I center the `0_{3 \times 3}` in this matrix.
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath,arydshln}
\author{someone}
\title{something}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc;{1pt/2pt}ccc}
    0&1&0&&&\\
    0&0&1&&&\\
    2&1&-1&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\raisebox{\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip+.3\ht\strutbox+0\height}[0pt][0pt]{\scalebox{2}{$0_{\scaleto{3\times 3}{3pt}}$}}}
    \end{array}\right]
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Matirx]

Is there no easier way to create a matrix like this with some package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath,arydshln}
\author{someone}
\title{something}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    A=\left[\begin{array}{c;{1pt/2pt}c}
        \begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
            0&1&0\\
            0&0&1\\
            2&1&-1
        \end{array}&
        \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
            \scalebox{2}{$0_{\scaleto{3\times 3}{3pt}}$}
        \end{array}
    \end{array}\right]
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've not seen @ being used like this in array. Can you further your explaining of what you have done?

Comment: @Al_Fh `@{<a>}` will add `<a>` between the column at the position. Try with `@{AlFh}`, you will see the difference. I use `@{}` to remove all space between the text of the columns. See more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207463/156344

Comment: Thanks for the response, Greatly appreciated